# 3 Google docs combined into 1?

Tags: google-docs

I have a little project I am working on, and would like to know more.

Is it possible to Have 3 google docs (A,B,C), and have them updated into 1 Master Google doc page?

For example, if I were to input data on Document A, I would be able to see the information automatically listed on the Master document? Same with B, and C.

I am willing to learn/work on this, just would like to know if its even possible and hope that you can help me or point me in the right direciton.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Due to [this link](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/sXhNvAL0l3c) it seems merging is not possible for now. Copy-Paste is a way to go but that is not what you're looking for.

by the way, Google Document has been renamed to Google Drive lately. And this is a work in progress. has lots of limitations. It's not a solution to everything. The most useful feature of it is real-time editing.

AFAIK `LaTeX` can do that with if you like a new challenge.

Comment: @Marty Recently I found LaTeX to be easy and powerful. but it take a little time to get familiar to. It basically depend on your document. If it's important to you and you have to work on it for long time then I recommend you to use `LaTeX`. But if it's a document you want to write and leave it and you just want to make it fast and easy then you can use a office suit write such as `libreoffice write`. If you need to work with someone else in real-time then you can use google drive to make a drafts in separate documents and then copy-paste them to LaTeX or an office suit and finalize it.

Comment: Yes, the three google documents would be constantly updated for years to come. We would need the Master document to reflect changes in google Docs A,B, and C. Therefore, I think LaTex would be the best bet, correct?

Comment: @Marty You won't regret it. If it is a long time project then go with LaTeX. Install texlive and texmaker and get a template and work with it. Don't be disappointing before 2 weeks. At first it is hard but when you learned it you will love it. There is a stack like site devoted to LaTeX Q&A named tex.stackexchange.com